# openssl.dll is not loading on php? Any Reason?

Tags: php, apache, openssl

I have enabled the **OpenSSL** extension in he `php.ini`, I have copied multiple `dll` files from the **PHP** folder into the **Apache**'s `bin' folder and the **System 32** folder but **OpenSSL** is still not enabled on my system. Why?

Comment: restart apache after changing php.ini!?

Comment: Yes sir, Eventhough it is not loading

Comment: `apache\conf\openssl.cnf,  apache\ bin\libeay32.dll , apache\  bin\ssleay32.dll , apache\bin\openssl.exe ` this minimum settinge require for use . have you done it?

Comment: yes sir, i did everything what you have said already.But it is not coming @gaurav

Comment: How dit you 'enable' openssl? Please provide some steps ...

Comment: Yes sir, 1.Enabled openssl,apache\conf\openssl.cnf, apache\ bin\libeay32.dll , apache\ bin\ssleay32.dll , apache\bin\openssl.exe